# Create multiple different dynamic components using ngFor directive Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to insert a dynamic list of components inside parent component template using ngFor directive to create ng-template host placeholders for each component in the list. What I have tried:

component template where dynamic components will be inserted:

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components;let i = index">
     <ng-template #dynamiccomponenthost></ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
 @Input()
components: any;

@ViewChildren('dynamiccomponenthost', { read: ViewContainerRef }) cHost: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.loadComponents();
    }

private loadComponents(): void {
    this.cHost.map((vcr: ViewContainerRef, index: number) => {
      
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.components[index].component);
       
        vcr.clear();

        vcr.createComponent(factory);
    });
```

'components' input is an array of objects containing the dynamic component instances in the following form:

```
[ 
   { 'component' : DynamicComponent1 },
   { 'component' : DynamicComponent2 }
]
```

Using *ngFor the dynamic components are not rendered in the DOM. I have tried also to create ng-template placeholder host hardcoded inside the template:

component template:

```
<div >
   <ng-template #kalasehost></ng-template>
 </div>
 <div >
   <ng-template #kalasehost></ng-template>
 </div>
```

Using this template markup dynamic templates are rendered as expected. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong using ngFor directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the provblem solved by using trackBy inside *ngFor loop

component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components;trackBy:identify;let i = index">
 <ng-template #dynamiccomponenthost></ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
identify(index, item) {
    return item && item.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem and write an article on medium
https://medium.com/@teslenkooleg2017/angular-13-create-multiple-dynamic-components-using-directive-ngfor-effe0850a69d

```
//component.html
    <div *ngFor="let car of cars">
          <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
        </div>

// component.ts

 @ViewChildren('dynamic', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamic: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

    private loadComponent(): void {
        this.dynamic.map((vcr: ViewContainerRef, index: number) =>{
          vcr.clear();
          this.componentRef = vcr.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
          this.componentRef.instance.title = this.cars[index].title;
          this.componentRef.instance.text = this.cars[index].text;
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ngComponentOutlet`

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components" [ngComponentOutlet]="component.component"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it isn't really helpful in this situation...the problem fixed by using trackBy inside ngFor loop...